# Substitute command for ChildFieldEvent?

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to make an interactive PDF Form using iText and I have used this command:

```
PdfFormField personal = PdfFormField.createEmpty(writer); 
personal.setFieldName("personal"); 
PdfPTable table= new PdfPTable(3); 
PdfPCell cell; 
cell= new PdfPCell(); 
cell.setColspan(2); 
TextField field = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(0,0),"name"); 
field.setFontSize(12);
cell.setCellEvent(new ChildFieldEvent(personal, field.getTextField(), 1));
table.addCell(cell);
```

But it's showing

> ChildFieldEvent cannot be resolved into a type

Is there any substitute command for it?

Comment: Are you basing your code on http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=239 ? If so, have you noticed the introduction of that example? It says *Note that this example depends on ChildFieldEvent, and maybe some other examples.* :)

Comment: Thank You sir for bringing it to my notice :)